# java program to read excel file and create an array to insert it to database table

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am writing a java program with the help of apache poi to read from excel file.I want to write a program which creates arrays of object from  excel, and  update the DB.

I am able to read the  excel file with the help of apache poi(using the examples provides) but after reading excel file, i am not sure  how to  create array in java which has all the data.
The first row  represents the  table field (i.e.  column name: EX name,id,etc..)

1)The  logic should be smart enough to detect  columns even if the order are reversed/changed  in excel file.
Example of table :

---

Code :

```
XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
    Iterator < Row >  rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
    while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
        row = (XSSFRow) rowIterator.next();
        Iterator < Cell >  cellIterator = row.cellIterator();

        while ( cellIterator.hasNext()) {
           Cell cell = cellIterator.next();

           switch (cell.getCellType()) {
              case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
              System.out.print( 
              cell.getNumericCellValue() + " \t\t " );
              break;

              case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
              /*System.out.print(
              cell.getStringCellValue() + " \t\t " );
              */break;
           }
        }
        System.out.println();
     }
```

Comment: Add your code to this post, noone can help you without it. Also, are you trying to fill a database with the data from your excel file?

Comment: where is your code????

Comment: Your question should be clear including your current code snippet..please avoid asking for direct logic without showing your code efforts here

Comment: i am  submitting my code, give a minute

Comment: if you want to insert the data from the excel file into a database, why store it in an array? that will only require you to write more code. simply insert the data into the database while reading the file.

Comment: i m new to java and just want to try it out.

Comment: I was able to find the ans, will post  my solution in sometime

Answer (score 1):

```
     XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
        Iterator < Row >  rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
// using for loop on rows of excel sheet
        for(int i=sheet.getFirstRowNum()+1;i<=sheet.getLastRowNum();i++){
              Row ro=sheet.getRow(i);
              for(int j=ro.getFirstCellNum();j<ro.getLastCellNum();j++){
                   Cell ce = ro.getCell(j);
                   DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();
                   String str = formatter.formatCellValue(ce);
            //add the logic to update the aaray         
            }

        }
```